# (Angular 4) Highcharts changing data doesn't update chart

Tags: angular, highcharts, binding

I have a chart like this:

```
<chart [options]="options"></chart>
```

where the options are defined in the component constructor like this:

```
options;

initChart(){
    this.options = {
      title : { text : 'original title' },
      series: [{
        data: [],
      }]
    };
  }
```

Now when I call this function:

```
changeTitle(){
  this.options.title.text = 'different title';
  console.log(this.options.title.text);
}
```

I can see in the console that the title changed, but in the chart itself it's still the original title.

However, if I create a new options object and overwrite the old one like this:

```
  changeTitle2(){
    this.options = {
      title : { text : 'different title' },
      series: [{
        data: [],
      }]
    };
  }
```

Everything works fine. Now I don't want to do it this way, because I want to be able to just push additional data points to the chart without redrawing everything like presented here: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

I realise they use a chart object there, not a JSON object for the data, but for some reason, I am unable to create a chart object in the component using `var x = Highcharts.chart(...);`, I get this error I don't understand:

> 'Highcharts' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.

I tried importing everything, but it just won't work...

Comment: You can use methods for dynamic chart update offers by Highcharts API like chart.update() or series.addPoint() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.addPoint If you want to change a title only - use chart.update({ title: ... })